# Form with a list of files, secured with password

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to create a dropdown menu on my web page with files in it. User needs to enter the password to see these files. It's no need to be encrypted. How do I do that

Something [like this](http://prntscr.com/noe0uo), but the user will need to enter the password to see this files.

```
<div class="toggler">Ostalo</div>
<div class="element">
  <%                    
    info = new DirectoryInfo("\\Ostalo\something");
    files = info.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();

    foreach (FileInfo dat in files) {
      var test=dat;
      if(test.ToString() != "Thumbs.db"){
  %>
  <li class="seznam_razmak"><a  href="/Doc/<%=dat%>" class="link1" target="_blank">&nbsp&nbsp<%=dat%></a></li>

  <%
  }}%>
</div>
```

how do I secure that with password

Comment: Have a normal login system, if logged in, show ability to show files.

Comment: You mean to say password needs to be entered to show the list of files?

Comment: @SuhasKulkarni Yes

Comment: You need to rethink your design. Pouring C# code in your ASP page's `div` element to require a password isn't good design.

Comment: @KobyDouek I don't care about design. I just need to work

Comment: Exactly. Agree with @KobyDouek. The list of files can be easily accessed from the browser's console. Not sure what pattern you want to use, but I would say, write an API in controller with Authorization Attribute to see if the user is valid by checking the password, and then return list of files to the front end with AjaxResult.

Comment: @patriot16 If you don't care about design, then deal with this poor choise on your own, I don't think you will be able to get help here when you clearly don't understand the basics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a text input and compare the value to your password:

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server" />`

Add a button to submit causing the page to reload, because server side changes only take effect after a round trip to server:

`<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />`

And wrap your output code in a conditional:

```
<div class="element">
  <%
    if (txtPassword.Text == "password") {
      ...
    }
  %>
</div>
```

Comment: You are encouraging the OP for very very bad pratices. This code will be used by future SO visitors. No need to answer the OP if he writes "I don't care about design".

Comment: If a requirement is as simple as stated, why complicate things? You want to use a Model-View-Controller setup just for checking a password? Simple questions can have simple answers, too.

Comment: @Willem thank you this works perfect for me and I know that this is not the most secure option.

Comment: Sorry but it's not just "not the most secure option" but actually it is the "most insecure design".

Comment: Are you storing your passwords in plain text? That is a terrible idea.